# Probability calculation with large numbers

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, binomial-coefficients

I do have a probability measure:

$P = 1 - \dfrac{k!\, \binom{2^{32}} {k}}{(2^{32})^k}$,

where $k$ is an positive integer.

Yet, I do have trouble evaluating it in terms of a numerical plot, as the values are too large. Even simplifications by expanding the binomial coefficient didn't help. I'd be interested in a plot of P over k and of a numerical result for 
$P(k) \overset{!}{=} 0.5$.

Comment: Hint: If I did not made a mistake you can compute without large numbers and modest $k$: $$\frac{k!\binom{2^{32}} {k}}{(2^{32})^k}
=\frac{k!\prod_{i=1}^{k}(\frac{2^{32}-(k-i)}{i})} {(2^{32})^k}
= \prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{(k-i)}{2^{32}}\right)
$$

Comment: I came to that conclusion as well. In a few more lines that your beautiful line +1. I recognize the product (probably from here) but I can not remember if it had a closed form..it feels like it should :).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve for $k\approx 77200$. Btw. what you helped me to derive is the amount of objects(mapped to a checksum) required such that the probability of a 32bit checksum collision exeeds 50%.

Comment: Is this to be applied to the birthday attack on a hash code?  ETA: Ahh, looks like it.

Comment: @briantung can expand upon this? Is it something I should be concerned to be a party of?

Comment: No, I guess you shouldn't be worried. I'm just calculating a checksum and I'm asking myself, for how many objects can I do this before it becomes risky that two objects retrieve the same checksum. Btw. for a 16 bit checksum, the amount of objects required, such that the probability of a checksum collision exeeds 50% is 300, only. Intrestingly this probability measure (I didn't know abotu this either, till Brian's post) is also used in the field of cryptographical attacks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack

Comment: @Chinny84: Not at all.  See the link in Flo Ryan's comment (the Wikipedia article on "birthday attack").  It is the lowest-common-denominator attack on any cryptographic hash, but it also has relevance to non-crypto checksum colliisions.  Still the same problem in essence, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $1-a=\exp(\ln(1-a))\approx\exp(-a)$ for small values of $a$ and
$$
1+2+…+(k-1)+k=\frac{k(k+1)}2\approx \frac{k^2}2
$$
one gets
$$
P(k)=1-\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac j{2^{32}}\right)\approx 1-\exp\left(-\frac{k^2}{2^{33}}\right)
$$
Solving this for $P(k)=0.5$ results in the approximation
$$
k\approx \sqrt{-\ln(1-0.5)·2^{33}}=77 162.74…
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
1 - \frac{k!\left(\matrix{2^{32}\\k}\right)}{\left(2^{32}\right)^k}
$$
lets expand we find
$$
1 - \frac{k!\frac{2^{32}!}{k!\left(2^{32}-k\right)!}}{\left(2^{32}\right)^k} = 1 - \frac{2^{32}!}{\left(2^{32}\right)^k\left(2^{32}-k\right)!}
$$
notice that
$$
\frac{2^{32}!}{\left(2^{32}-k\right)!} = 2^{32}\left(2^{32}-1\right)\cdots\left(2^{32}-(k-1)\right)
$$
matching the terms with the numerator
$$
P = 1 - \frac{2^{32}\left(2^{32}-1\right)\cdots\left(2^{32}-(k-1)\right)}{\left(2^{32}\right)^k} = 1 - 1\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{32}}\right)\cdots\left(1 -\frac{(k-1)}{2^{32}}\right)
$$
thus you get
$$
P = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{2^{32}}\right)
$$
I am still working on the last part, namely 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{2^{32}}\right) = ?
$$
Going by your preliminary work it should be $0.5$ but I need to see it from the above.

Comment: You switched the minus for a plus sign? Use $(1-a_1)…(1-a_k)\approx 1-\sum a_j$ or $\approx \exp(-\sum a_j)$ for small $a_j$ and moderate amount $k$ to get an approximate result (or to conclude that this approximation is to coarse).

Comment: Thank you @lutzl. I saw an approximation like that for terms $\left(1+p_i\right)$ where $p_i >0$ can you apply the same rational for $p_i < 0$?

Comment: Yes, the only condition is that $p_i$ is small, since then $\ln(1+p_i)\approx p_i$. Still, you have to address how you get terms greater 1 from terms smaller 1.

Comment: @lutzl ￼Sorry. I thought you said you changed the equations in my post. It is indeed meant to be a minus sign. Thank you.